# Select two comparers in two list with same property value

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I want to compare two `List<Candidate>` and select both entities with same value in the `Hash` property.

```
public class  Candidate : IEquatable<Candidate>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public String Hash { get; set; }
}

//....

//List with "CandidateA", "CandidateB", "CandidateC" values
List<Candidate> newsCandidate = loadNewsCandidate();

//List with "CandidateC' " , "CandidateD", "CandidateE" values
List<Candidate> previousCandidate = loadPreviousCandidate();

//CandidateC and CandidateC' has same 'Hash' value.

//This return "CandidateC" in newsCandidate
var common = newsCandidate.Where(n => previousCandidate.Any(p => p.Hash.Equals(n.Hash))).ToList();
```

I want retrieve a `List<Tuple<Candidate,Candidate>>` or similar, with elements `n.CandidateC` and `p.CandidateC'` and output a message similar to:

```
 $"Previous Name: {p.CandidateC.Name} to New Name: {n.CandidateC.Name}"
```

Will apreciate any help.

Comment: what is the key that joins the old and the new?

Comment: The 'Hash' property join the old and new items in the lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest thing to do would be to create a `Dictionary` from the previous candidates and lookup each match:

```
var prevDict = previousCandidate.ToDictionary(pc => pc.Hash);
var ans = newsCandidate.Select(nc => prevDict.TryGetValue(nc.Hash, out var pc) ? new { pc, nc } : null).Where(pcnc => pcnc != null);
```

If you prefer not to manually build your own `Dictionary`, you can also use the LINQ `Join` to do the same thing:

```
var ansj = previousCandidate.Join(newsCandidate, pc => pc.Hash, nc => nc.Hash, (pc, nc) => new { pc, nc });
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems `GroupBy` could be useful:

```
var p = new List<Candidate> 
{ 
    new Candidate { Name = "John", Hash = "1" }, 
    new Candidate { Name = "Mike", Hash = "2" } 
};

var n = new List<Candidate> 
{ 
    new Candidate { Name = "Mike", Hash = "1" }, 
    new Candidate { Name = "John", Hash = "2" } 
};

var joined = p.Concat(n).GroupBy(item => item.Hash);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", joined
    .Where(g => g.Count() == 2)
    .Select(g => $"Old name {g.First().Name}, New name {g.Last().Name}")));

// Old name John, new name Mike
// Old name Mike, new name John
```

or just make `List<Tuple<Candidate, Candidate>>` with:

```
List<Tuple<Candidate, Candidate>> tuple = joined
    .Where(g => g.Count() == 2)
    .Select(g => new Tuple<Candidate, Candidate>(g.First(), g.Last()))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: That seems really convoluted. Why not use `p.Concat(n)` instead of `new[].SelectMany`? Why not use `Join` instead of making one the inefficient way?